# How do you "fake" the signature of a Solidity event?

Tags: solidity, events

The Note for the [official Solidity documentation on Events](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.20/contracts.html#events) says that "it is possible to “fake” the signature of another event using an anonymous event", without going into details of the process.

So, how do you "fake" the signature of an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of “Solidity events” like `emit Value(123)` does not exist at the EVM level. At the EVM level, there are only the functions `LOG0`, `LOG1`, `LOG2`, `LOG3` and `LOG4`. Every `LOG` function “logs” a number of data `bytes`, indexed with 0 to 4 `bytes32` “topics” (later events can be looked up by these topics). When you emit an “event” in Solidity, the non-`indexed` event arguments are ABI-encoded to `bytes` and passed as the `data` argument to `LOG`, and the `indexed` events are passed as the topics… but Solidity also squeezes in the “event signature”, hashed, as an extra (first) topic (to make it easy to look up e.g. all ERC-20 `Transfer(address,uint256,uint256)` events)… unless an event is marked as `anonymous`, in which case it squeezes in nothing.

So the output of the following two `emit`s is indistinguishable on the blockchain:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

contract Test {

    event Value(uint256 value);

    event NameDoesntMatter(bytes32 indexed topic0, uint256 value) anonymous;

    function test() external {
        emit Value(123);
        emit NameDoesntMatter(keccak256(bytes("Value(uint256)")), 123);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you did there is quite witty! Thank you for the example!

Comment: This whole "faking" thing is not too helpful for an actual mal-intended actor, though, is it? If I'd like to "fake" the event from a contract, I could just copy the event declaration fully in my own contract - and emit it from there, without making my event `anonymous`, could I not?

Comment: You’re welcome. No it is not possible to completely fake an event from someone else’s contract, because even if you emit an event with the same name and values as you describe, you will not be able to “spoof” the address of the contract emitting the event, which is an integral part of an event. One reason why one might want to “fake” the “event name” could be to generate it dynamically at runtime based on some logic. Keep in mind that it is also possible to “fake” events by invoking the [inline-assembly](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/yul.html#evm-dialect) `log` functions directly.